# Qt binary linked to both Qt 5 and (wrongly) to Qt 4 causing segmentation fault when linked to Qwt

Tags: qt, cmake, ros, qwt

I have a Qt / ROS / Qwt application. Everything was going fine until I tried to link to Qwt. Note that I'm using Qwt 6.1.2 which should run on Qt 5.5. Indeed, the examples run fine.

When I run my binary, it crashes even if I'm not using Qwt. I just need to link the my code to Qwt for that to happen. And -here is the issue I think-, gdb gives the following error:

```
ram received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff25eadfc in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
```

Which is wrong since the binary should  be using Qt 5.5. To make things more weird, ldd gives:

```
>> ldd dls_gui | grep 'Qt'
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f684cadc000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f684afad000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f684a867000)
    libQtSvg.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4 (0x00007f684862c000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f6847979000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f6847493000)
    libicui18n.so.54 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.54 (0x00007f6844e33000)
    libicuuc.so.54 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.54 (0x00007f6844a85000)
    libicudata.so.54 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.54 (0x00007f684305b000)
```

How can I be linked to both Qt5 and Qt4? Qwt seems to be linked to only Qt 5.5:

```
>> ldd /usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib/libqwt.so | grep 'Qt'
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007fbcee13a000)
    libQt5Svg.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Svg.so.5 (0x00007fbcedee5000)
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x00007fbcedc8e000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fbced410000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fbcecbfc000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fbcec4b7000)
    libicui18n.so.54 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.54 (0x00007fbcea032000)
    libicuuc.so.54 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.54 (0x00007fbce9c84000)
    libicudata.so.54 => /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.54 (0x00007fbce825a000)
```

My CMakeList.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(dls_gui)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Qwt related
# list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_packages")
# find_package(Qwt REQUIRED)
find_path(QWT_INCLUDE_DIR qwt.h HINTS /usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/include)
find_library(QWT_LIBRARY qwt /usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib/)
include_directories(${QWT_INCLUDE_DIR})


# catkin related
catkin_package()
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp sensor_msgs urdf)
include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)

# source, header and resources files list
set(CPP_SOURCES src/main.cpp src/mainwindow.cpp src/basewidget.cpp src/rosQtNode.cpp 
    src/joints_sliders.cpp src/superslider.cpp src/support_polygon.cpp)

set(CPP_HDRS include/mainwindow.h include/basewidget.h include/rosQtNode.hpp 
    include/joints_sliders.hpp include/superslider.hpp include/support_polygon.hpp)

set(QRC_RESOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dls_gui.qrc)

# Add the include directories for the Qt 5 Widgets module to# the compile lines.
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Use the compile definitions defined in the Qt 5 Widgets module
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

# Generate headers from ui files
qt5_wrap_ui(UIS_HDRS src/mainwindow.ui)

# Generate moc files from cpp
qt5_wrap_cpp(MOC_SOURCES ${CPP_SOURCES} ${CPP_HDRS})

# Generate resources 
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES_RCC ${RESOURCE})

# Add compiler flags for building executables (-fPIE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

## Ros include dirs
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(dls_gui ${CPP_SOURCES}  ${UIS_HDRS} ${MOC_SOURCES} ${QRC_RESOURCES})
add_executable(testRos src/testRos.cpp)
qt5_use_modules(dls_gui Widgets)

#Link the helloworld executable to the Qt 5 widgets library.
target_link_libraries(dls_gui ${QWT_LIBRARY} Qt5::Widgets ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )

target_link_libraries(testRos ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I don't think this is ROS related, nevertheless, is important to say that the source code is compiled via catkin_make etc.

Last but not least, qmake refers to version 5.5:

```
>> qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.0 in /home/jcolmenares/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib
```

EDIT: Just to be clear: I want (need) everything compiled and linked to the same Qt versión. But somehow,  is not happening.

Comment: `I don't think this is ROS related...` - Then try to eliminate ROS usage in your example. As you say that `I just need to link the my code to Qwt for crash to happen`, it shouldn't be a hard task to eliminate tools which don't affect on the problem in question. But in any case, according to [this mailing](https://forum.qt.io/topic/9354/can-an-application-depend-on-multiple-versions-of-qt-one-directly-and-the-other-through-a-3rd-party-library/4) **mixing QT versions in one executable is a bad idea**.

Comment: all required platform plugins and other plugins will sure be confused as well.  This is really a bad idea to link different versions of qt in one binary

Comment: Of course mixing qt versions is a bad idea. the question is how to avoid it! The binary should be linked to qt 5 only not both. That's what is on the CMakeList file. Did you read the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I switched everything back to Qt4. Got tired of wasting time on an issue that should not happen. Still have no idea how the binary ended linked to two different versions of Qt, only when linked to Qwt, where Qwt was linked only to Qt5 and the binary without the linkage to Qwt was also only linked to Qt5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with `qwt-qt5`.

`qwt` is the Qt4 version of QWT, which uses `libQtGui.so.4` etc., which you can see in your `ldd` output above. Linking with `qwt-qt5` only requires Qt5 `so` files.